# How to add new label to boxlayout from popup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popup, kivy

I have screen that has two boxlayouts. first one is empty. second one has button to open popup. In popup i have 2 textinputs and checkbox.  I want to add those textinputs as a labels to that boxlayout and checkbox as well.

I can add button to boxlayout if i have button on that screen. but once we go to popup i cant figure out how to do it.

Py.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class MyPopup(Popup):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def fire_popup(self):
        pops = MyPopup()
        pops.open()

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def changescreen(self, value):

        try:
            if value !='main':
                self.current = value
        except:
            print('No Screen named'+ value)




class testiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Hello'

    def add_more(self):
        addbutton = self.root.get_screen('Page2').ids.empty
        addbutton.add_widget(Button(text='Hello'))

    def remove(self):
        container = self.root.get_screen('Page2').ids.empty
        if len(container.children) > 0:
            container.remove_widget(container.children[0])

testiApp().run()
```

Kv.

```
<MyPopup>:
    id:pop
    size_hint: .4, .4
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'XXX!!'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            Label:
                text:'X1'
            TextInput:
                id: X1

            Label:
                text:'X2'
            TextInput:
                id:X2

            CheckBox:
                id:X3

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            Button:
                text:'Add'
                on_release: app.add_more()
            Button:
                text: 'Close'
                on_press: pop.dismiss()


ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
        name:'Main'
    SecondScreen:
        name:'Page2'



<MainScreen>:
    name:'Main'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:'Next Page'
            on_release: app.root.current ='Page2'



<SecondScreen>:
    name:'Page2'


    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            Label:
                text:'Popup Test'
            ScrollView:
                GridLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    row_default_height: 60
                    cols:1
                    id:empty
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    text:'Open Popup'
                    on_press: root.fire_popup()

                Button:
                    text:'Add'
                    on_release: app.add_more()

                Button:
                    text:'remove'
                    on_release: app.remove()
```

Comment: Except for the `text= root.` error in your `add_more()` method, it seems to work fine for me. Perhaps it's not clear what you want.

Comment: i was playing with the code and accidentally added with that text= root. originally it was just text='hello'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question

> I want to add those textinputs as a labels to that boxlayout and
>   checkbox as well.

## Solution

The solution involves enhancements to the kv file and Python script.

### kv file

- Implement the view for class rule, `<Row>:`
- Pass the values of `X1`, `X2`, `X3` to method `add_more()`
- Optional: add attributes to `ScrollView:`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<Row>:
    x1: ''
    x2: ''
    x3: False

    Label:
        text: root.x1
    Label:
        text: root.x2
    CheckBox:
        active: root.x3

<MyPopup>:
    ...

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            Button:
                text:'Add'
                on_release: app.add_more(X1.text, X2.text, X3.active)
...

<SecondScreen>:
    ...

            ScrollView:
                bar_width: 10
                bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
                bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
                effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
                scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
```

### py file

- Declare a `class Row()` with inheritance of `BoxLayout`.
- Declare class attributes for `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` of type `StringProperty` and `BooleanProperty`
- Implement a constructor to populate `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`
- Modify method `add_more()` to accept `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`

#### Snippets - py file

```
class Row(BoxLayout):
    x1 = StringProperty('')
    x2 = StringProperty('')
    x3 = BooleanProperty(False)

    def __init__(self, x1, x2, x3, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.x3 = x3


class testiApp(App):
    ...
    def add_more(self, x1, x2, x3):
        addbutton = self.root.get_screen('Page2').ids.empty
        addbutton.add_widget(Row(x1, x2, x3))
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks ikolim, you are the king! That is exactly what i wanted to achieve. It all seems so simple once you see it. I knew i needed string and booleanproperty but i was too novice to figure out how to structure this all. Big thanks!

Comment: By the way do you have ideas how to remove the Row which is made from popup? I can add 4th widget on the row which is remove button. So then with clicking that button this specific row where the button is would be removed.

Comment: Please open a new question for removing a specific row. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you can get the `text` from your `TextInput` by saving a reference to the `MyPopup` that gets created in your `SecondScreen`:

```
class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def fire_popup(self):
        self.pops = MyPopup()
        self.pops.open()
```

Then use that reference in your `add_more()` method:

```
def add_more(self):
    addbutton = self.root.get_screen('Page2').ids.empty
    addbutton.add_widget(Button(text=self.root.current_screen.pops.ids.X1.text))
```

Of course, you can reference the `X2` similarly.

Comment: If i replace your suggested add_more to original add_more and try to add new button i will get this error message 'SecondScreen' object has no attribute 'pops'

Comment: You also must modify the `SecondScreen` as above.

Comment: Your `Add` button (the one not in the `Popup`) needs its own, different `add_more()`.